# Utilizing AND statement (two conditions) inside react ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, jsx, logical-operators

below is a inline if with logical && operator that renders a component if `this.state.isHidden` is false.

```
<div>{!this.state.isHidden && <ShowThisComponent /> }</div>
```

The above line works as expected. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to add a second condition to be met (e.g var1 === var2) to the above line. So that if both return true, the component gets displayed. How can I do this? thanks

I've looked at the documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical-ampamp-operator) could not find an answer

Comment: Just add another && statement with var1 === var2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how the operator works:

`{<any boolean statement> && <Component-to-be-displayed />}`.

-or-

`{(<any boolean statement>) && <Component-to-be-displayed />}` ... it's always a good idea to use parentheses when analysing boolean statements

In your case it would look something like this :

`(!this.state.isHidden &&  var1 === var2) && <Component-to-be-displayed />`

so think of the operator like this:

*if condition is true && render component*

You can also perform an if-statement:

`{(<any boolean statement>) ?
 <Component-to-be-displayed-if-true />
  :
 <Component-to-be-displayed-if-false />
}`

you can think of this operator like this:

*if condition is true ? render component A : else render component B*

Comment: Hi lets say I want to add an else condition at the end in case the conditions returned false. I tried this but it fails: (!this.state.isHidden &&  var1 === var2) ? <Component-to-be-displayed /> : <Somthing />

Comment: you have to surround it with braces {}
like this: `{ (!this.state.isHidden && var1 === var2) ? <Component-to-be-displayed /> : <Somthing />} `

Comment: that is exactly what I have but it shows both components right on top off eachother

Comment: okay, maybe you could try using parenthesis for the boolean statements? Like this: `{ ( (!this.state.isHidden) && (var1 === var2)) ? <Component-to-be-displayed /> : <Somthing /> }`

Comment: same result as before

Comment: do you mind sharing the actual code with me? you can send me a skype message. My id is dakoto747

Answer (score 6):

```
{ (!this.state.isHidden && var1 === var2) && <ShowThisComponent /> }
```

Comment: inner ( ) are unneccessary. Acutally, Prettier would remove them.

Comment: Sometimes brackets are useful for visual clarity/ emphasis, rather than any real necessity

Comment: @SebastijanDumančić  If we need to add more than 1 condition, It becomes more readable with parentheses.

Comment: I don't agree. If there are more than 2 conditions, it's usually recommended to break them into multiple lines so you would have each condition in new line, ending with &&.

Comment: @SebastijanDumančić  Yes its always a best practice to break the condition into seperate line. But when using two conditions it makes much sence to keep them in parantheses for better readability.

Answer (score 3):

```
{ !this.state.isHidden && secondCondition && <ShowThisComponent /> }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation along with your code. Thank you!