# Can I pass several props into one rule of a styled component (react.js)

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have build this slider, and want that the icon left has an opacity: 0.5, when the first picture is shown. If the last picture is shown, than the icon "right" shoud have opacity:0.5. How can I do this with props in styled-components? Thanks for your help.

This not works: opacity: ${props=>props.direction === "left" && props.id === 1 && "0.5"};

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import {IoIosArrowForward, IoIosArrowBack} from "react-icons/io";
import { bilderserie } from "../data";
import { useState } from "react";
const Container = styled.div`
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background: #242121;
    position:relative;
`;
const Icon = styled.span`
    background:transparent;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: 2px solid var(--white);
    border-radius:50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    left: ${props=>props.direction ==="left" && "20"}px;
    right: ${props=>props.direction ==="right" && "20"}px;
    z-index:3;
    cursor: pointer;
        & .arrow{
            color: var(--white);
            font-size: 40px;
        }
`;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    overflow:hidden;
`;
const SliderItem = styled.div`
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transform: translateX(${props=>props.slideIndex * - 100}%);
`;
const ImageHolder = styled.div`
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;

`;
const Img = styled.img`
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
`;
const ContentHolder = styled.div`
    width:100vw;
    height:200px;
    position:sticky;
    bottom:0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    padding:20px;
`;
const Content = styled.p`
    color: var(--white);
`;

const Bilderserien = () => {
        const [sliderPosition, setSliderPosition] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = (name)=>{
            if(name === "left"){
                setSliderPosition(sliderPosition > 0 ? sliderPosition -1 : 0);
            }
            else{
                setSliderPosition(sliderPosition < 4 ? sliderPosition +1 : 4);
            }
    }
    
  return (
    <Container>
        <Icon direction="left" onClick={()=>handleClick("left")} id={bilderserie.id}>
            <IoIosArrowBack className="arrow"/>
        </Icon>
        <Wrapper>
            {
                bilderserie.map((serie)=>(
                    <SliderItem key={serie.id} slideIndex={sliderPosition}>
                        <ImageHolder>
                            <Img src={serie.img} alt={serie.alt} title={serie.title}/>
                        </ImageHolder>
                        <ContentHolder>
                                <Content>{serie.content}</Content>
                            </ContentHolder>
                    </SliderItem>
                ))
            }
        </Wrapper>
        <Icon direction="right" onClick={()=>handleClick("right")} id={bilderserie.id}>
            <IoIosArrowForward className="arrow"/>
        </Icon>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Bilderserien
```

Comment: You do not have an `opacity` property in your code.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. This what not works, stands seperatly above the code. It was inserted in Icon for saying: "look if there is a prop with the name "description" and a value "left" and if there is a second prop with the name "id" and the value "1", then set this Icon to opacity 0.5. But this not works. So perhaps I have a mistake in my syntax or it is impossible to pass two props into one rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when anyone want to build a Slider, where the icon left has an opacity: 0.5, when the first picture is shown. If the last picture is shown, than the icon "right" shoud have opacity:0.5
That's whats finally worked for me:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import {IoIosArrowForward, IoIosArrowBack} from "react-icons/io";
import { bilderserie } from "../data";
import { useState } from "react";
const Container = styled.div`
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background: #242121;
    position:relative;
`;
const Icon = styled.span`
    background:transparent;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: 2px solid var(--white);
    border-radius:50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    left: ${props=>props.direction ==="left" && "20"}px;
    right: ${props=>props.direction ==="right" && "20"}px;
    z-index:3;
    cursor: pointer;
        & .arrow{
            color: var(--white);
            font-size: 40px;
        }
`;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    overflow:hidden;
`;
const SliderItem = styled.div`
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transform: translateX(${props=>props.slideIndex * - 100}%);
`;
const ImageHolder = styled.div`
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;

`;
const Img = styled.img`
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
`;
const ContentHolder = styled.div`
    width:100vw;
    height:200px;
    position:sticky;
    bottom:0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    padding:20px;
`;
const Content = styled.p`
    color: var(--white);
`;

const Bilderserien = () => {
        const [sliderPosition, setSliderPosition] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = (name)=>{
            if(name === "left"){
                setSliderPosition(sliderPosition > 0 ? sliderPosition -1 : 0);
            }
            else{
                setSliderPosition(sliderPosition < 4 ? sliderPosition +1 : 4);
            }
    }
    
  return (
    <Container>
        <Icon direction="left" onClick={()=>handleClick("left")} style={sliderPosition === 0 ? {opacity:"0.5"} : {opacity:"1"}}>
            <IoIosArrowBack className="arrow"/>
        </Icon>
        <Wrapper>
            {
                bilderserie.map((serie)=>(
                    <SliderItem key={serie.id} slideIndex={sliderPosition}>
                        <ImageHolder>
                            <Img src={serie.img} alt={serie.alt} title={serie.title}/>
                        </ImageHolder>
                        <ContentHolder>
                                <Content>{serie.content}</Content>
                            </ContentHolder>
                    </SliderItem>
                ))
            }
        </Wrapper>
        <Icon direction="right" onClick={()=>handleClick("right")} style={sliderPosition === 4 ? {opacity:"0.5"} : {opacity:"1"}}>
            <IoIosArrowForward className="arrow"/>
        </Icon>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Bilderserien
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test this. Use parenthesis around your two conditions:

```
 opacity: ${props=>(props.direction === "left" && props.id === 1) && "0.5"};
```

**Note to:** [Utilizing AND statement (two conditions) inside react ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997358/utilizing-and-statement-two-conditions-inside-react-ternary-operator)

Comment: Hallo Arman, thank you for your answers, but I made a thinking fault. I fixed it, by using the useState, in which is the slideIndex, and insert following into my icons:  style={sliderPosition === 0 ? {opacity:"0.5"} : {opacity:"1"}} and the right one : style={sliderPosition === 4 ? {opacity:"0.5"} : {opacity:"1"}}. But your idea with the parenthesis, is very good.

Comment: @Roman You're welcome. So solved your problem? If so show your idea that it has solved that.

Comment: @Roman Thanks very much. is this has solved your problem?